# How to efficiently get a single tensor from a postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, tensorflow

I have a model which requires 2 timeseries from 2 postgres (timescale) table. This is my first try to get it :

```
m1, h1 = ( tfio.experimental.IODataset.from_sql(f'''
select col1, col2, col3 from (
select * from table_{t}
where timestamp <= '{timestamp_s}' order by timestamp desc limit 1000
) order by timestamp;
''', endpoint=endpoint) for t in ('m1', 'h1') )
```

But I get this value for m1 :

```
[{'col1': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=107750>,
  'col2': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=107793>,
  'col3': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=107741>,}
 {'col1': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=107777>,
  'col2': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=107796>,
  'col3': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=107751>,}]
```

While I would like to get a single tensor :

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(n_rows, n_cols), dtype=int32>
```

Is there a solution to get this tensor that would be efficient when training a model ?